# How to Install NumJs For Web Development?

Tags: javascript, html, installation

I'm trying to install NumJs for a website. I'm using this [article][1] as reference. I'm using VS Code and a live server. I'm assuming I would use browser installation. However, installing it like this:

```
<script>bower install numjs</script>
```

gave the error:`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

If I try using the other approach:

```html
<script src="bower_packages/numjs/dist/numjs.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var a = nj.array([2,3,4]);
</script>
```

I get the error: `numtest.html:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: nj is not defined`

Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong?
[1]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/numjs

Comment: This is not applicable! The script tags are HTML elements, but the command inside these tags is a Linux command that only work from command line (which is you could entered on host machine, or SSH connection)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open command line application or login to the remote server with SSH
2. Install NPM package manager (if not already installed):
   Follow these instruction which matches your system: https://linuxconfig.org/install-npm-on-linux#h1-install-npm-on-major-linux-distros
3. Install Bower (if not already installed): `npm install -g bower`
4. After that in open the root directory of your project (in terminal of course), and run this command: `bower install numjs`
5. Then your code should work

Comment: I'm running on Windows, so I don't think I would be able to complete step 2 using the command prompt. What would be the best way to run the Linux commands on Windows? Also, I'm able to install other libraries with a line of code so I'm a bit surprised numj requires so many steps; is there an easier way to use it?

Comment: @EphraimBryski NPM installation guide for Windows: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-node-js-npm-on-windows

Comment: I installed Node.js (I misunderstood what it meant by Node.js vs browser before, I thought Node.js was somewhere to write your code). I'm still a bit confused on the next line though var nj = require('numjs'); When I run it in Node.js it says 'var' is not recognized and when I run it in JavaScript it says 'require' is undefined.

Comment: Node.js is not enough! NPM is also required for execute your code 
https://nodejs.dev/learn/differences-between-nodejs-and-the-browser

Comment: It seems to have installed npm alongside node.js; when I run npm -v in node.js it outputs the version (6.14.8).

Comment: I seems the official documentation: this library is also available from CDN
`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/nicolaspanel/numjs@0.15.1/dist/numjs.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Thank you! Yes, just including that line in the HTML file worked. (I'm assuming installing Node was not necessary).